# How do I right justify a TextView in a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am trying to get the TextView, "tv_amount" to stay on the right side of the screen. I have tried using `android:gravity="right"` but that hasn't been working for me. Anyone have any suggestions?

**Image of emulator running this code:**

[image: image of emulator running this code]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_border"
        android:padding="6sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/food"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="Yummy Pizza"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="$25"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am expecting the transaction or "tv_amount" to stay be right justified so that end of the number is staying towards the right side of the screen.

I tried using :

```
android:layout_weight="0"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:gravity="right"
```

but these don't seem to work obviously. I am a beginner when it comes to android development and can't seem to find any answers that have helped anywhere else. They all say to use `android:gravity` or some other alternative. Maybe there is something in my code that doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am dumb. The issue wasn't with the code in my individual recycler view layout code. It was with my activity_main.xml. I set the recycler_view width to "wrap_content" when it should have been "match_parent." Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

Splitting the content into left and right will result in the weight and gravity properties working. Check out this layout below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
<!--Separate layout aligned to the left, containing an image and a yummy pizza label. -->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_text_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text Left"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    <!--Display the pizza price on a separate label aligned to the right -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Text Right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't quite work. It still is acting like a constraint layout would where the right text is "stuck" to the left. Should I try using a different layout? Or what else should I try?